# Connect fails with Error 91 (Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard)

Tags: c#, uwp, active-directory, ldap, novell

I've some problems with the integration of Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard (https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard) in C#. I'm using UWP and there is no integration of LDAP or On-Premise Active-Directory, therefore i have to use novell-directory.

But i cant get it to work ...

```
string ldapHost = "domain.local";
int ldapPort = 389;
LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection();
conn.Connect(ldapHost, ldapPort);
```

Fails with:
Cause = {"Der Zugriff auf einen Socket war aufgrund der Zugriffsrechte des Sockets unzulässig xx.xx.xx.xx:389"}

I also tried port 686 and SSL ... nothing works. Same error ... Any ideas?

Also tried an IP instead of the domain or the name of our Domain-Controller.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but it can be usefull for someone else...
I don't speak german, but I see something about socket.
Did you try to include SecureSocketLayer = true?

like `LdapConnection conn = new LdapConnection(){ SecureSocketLayer = true};`